# Child level object property binding in datagridview / controls in c# winforms application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am stuck in a problem while working with binding object list into datagridview or controls. Actually what I want, I have class say `Person`, `Address` and `Contact`. `Person` class have 3 properties one Name of type string, `Add` of type Address and last one is `Cont` of type `Contact`. By googling I found that I have to create `CustomTypeDescriptor` class which I created and it works for only one class either for `Contact` or for `Address`. When we put two times then it shows compile time error that can not have duplicate `[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(MyTypeDescriptionProvider<Contact>))]`.

How can I solve this problem.

Here I am providing sample code which I am trying to implement,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Name", "Name");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("City", "City");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ContactName", "ContactName");

        dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].DataPropertyName = "Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns["City"].DataPropertyName = "Add_City";
        dataGridView1.Columns["ContactName"].DataPropertyName = "Cont_ContactName";

        List<Person> PersonList = PersonProxy.GetPersonCollection();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = PersonList;
    }
}



public class PersonProxy
{
    public static List<Person> GetPersonCollection()
    {
        List<Person> persList = new List<Person>();

        persList.Add(new Person
        {
            Name = "Awadhendra",
            Add = new Address
            {
                City = "Allahabad"
            },
            Cont = new Contact
            {
                ContactName = "Awadh"
            }
        });

        persList.Add(new Person
        {
            Name = "Alok",
            Add = new Address
            {
                City = "Allahabad"
            },
            Cont = new Contact
            {
                ContactName = "Alok"
            }
        });

        persList.Add(new Person
        {
            Name = "Ankit",
            Add = new Address
            {
                City = "Lucknow"
            },
            Cont = new Contact
            {
                ContactName = "Ankit"
            }
        });

        persList.Add(new Person
        {
            Name = "Swati",
            Add = new Address
            {
                City = "Lucknow"
            },
            Cont = new Contact
            {
                ContactName = "Awadh"
            }
        });

        return persList;
    }
}


[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(MyTypeDescriptionProvider<Contact>))]    
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Add { get; set; }    ////How to get address and contact both for binding.        
    public Contact Cont { get; set; }  ////Write now am getting Contact
}

public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
}

public class MyTypeDescriptionProvider<T> : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    private ICustomTypeDescriptor td;
    public MyTypeDescriptionProvider()
        : this(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(Person)))
    {
    }
    public MyTypeDescriptionProvider(TypeDescriptionProvider parent)
        : base(parent)
    {
    }
    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        if (td == null)
        {
            td = base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);
            td = new MyCustomTypeDescriptor(td, typeof(T));
        }
        return td;
    }
}

public class SubPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private PropertyDescriptor _subPD;
    private PropertyDescriptor _parentPD;

    public SubPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor parentPD, PropertyDescriptor subPD, string pdname)
        : base(pdname, null)
    {
        _subPD = subPD;
        _parentPD = parentPD;
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
    public override void ResetValue(object component) { }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component) { return false; }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get { return _parentPD.ComponentType; }
    }
    public override Type PropertyType { get { return _subPD.PropertyType; } }

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return _subPD.GetValue(_parentPD.GetValue(component));
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        _subPD.SetValue(_parentPD.GetValue(component), value);
        OnValueChanged(component, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class MyCustomTypeDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    Type typeProperty;
    public MyCustomTypeDescriptor(ICustomTypeDescriptor parent, Type type)
        : base(parent)
    {
        typeProperty = type;
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection cols = base.GetProperties(attributes);

        string propertyName = "";
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor col in cols)
        {
            if (col.PropertyType.Name == typeProperty.Name)
                propertyName = col.Name;
        }
        PropertyDescriptor pd = cols[propertyName];
        PropertyDescriptorCollection children = pd.GetChildProperties();
        PropertyDescriptor[] array = new PropertyDescriptor[cols.Count + children.Count];
        int count = cols.Count;
        cols.CopyTo(array, 0);

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor cpd in children)
        {
            array[count] = new SubPropertyDescriptor(pd, cpd, pd.Name + "_" + cpd.Name);
            count++;
        }

        PropertyDescriptorCollection newcols = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(array);
        return newcols;
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider.aspx)

> There are two ways to associate a `TypeDescriptionProvider` with a `TypeDescriptor`:
>
> - At design time, when the target class can be assigned the appropriate    `TypeDescriptionProviderAttribute` tag.
> - At run time, when one of the `AddProvider` methods of the `TypeDescriptor` class can be called. These overloaded methods require either the target object or its class type.

So Just add them in runtime:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Name", "Name");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("City", "City");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("ContactName", "ContactName");

        dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].DataPropertyName = "Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns["City"].DataPropertyName = "Add_City";
        dataGridView1.Columns["ContactName"].DataPropertyName = "Cont_ContactName";

        List<Person> PersonList = PersonProxy.GetPersonCollection();

        //add them here
        System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.AddProvider((new MyTypeDescriptionProvider<Address>()), typeof(Person));
        System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.AddProvider((new MyTypeDescriptionProvider<Contact>()), typeof(Person));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = PersonList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found with .NET 4.5, the previous answer almost works, but the issue is that the AddProvider method acts as a last one wins, so we only see properties from Contract but not Address.

The solution is to chain the providers together so we get...

```
//add them here
var addressProvider = new MyTypeDescriptionProvider<Address>();
System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(t1, typeof(Person));
System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new MyTypeDescriptionProvider<Contact>(t1), typeof(Person));
```